# how to redeclare a variable in different datatypes in c

Tags: c, types

How can i redeclared a variable in c. I know this can not be declared directly as follows;

```
int k = 5;
float k = 12.5;
```

Is there any possible way to do like this?

Comment: No it's not possible to re*define* a variable using a different type in the same scope. Why do you want to do it? What is the actual problem you need to solve?

Comment: Honestly, if this was allowed, I would be extremely confused at code that used a feature like this. Why would you want to do this?

Comment: Would you also name all your five children and two dogs John and do so regardless of their gender?

Comment: @Ganchimeg Why do you need this?

Comment: I am just curious, thank u so much your answers

Comment: Curiosity is fine and a good motivator for learning. But please tell us, because if you had some other problem you were trying to solve then you should really ask about it directly.

Comment: Listen, folks, please don't be too hard on Ganchimeg here.  When you're just getting started in programming, it's not always obvious what's obviously possible versus what's obviously not.  Two people can have the same name, so why can't two variables?  (Yes, I know, two variables obviously can't.  But, again, we're not talking about what I know, or what you know.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamic typing is not supported in C as posted...

Yet there is a perverse way using the preprocessor (what else?) to make your code compile:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define xglue(a,b) a##b
#define glue(a,b) xglue(a,b)
#define k glue(k_, __LINE__)

int main() {
    int k = 5;      printf("k = %d\n", k);  // this really defines and uses k_8
    float k = 12.5; printf("k = %g\n", k);  // this really defines and uses k_9
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
k = 5
k = 12.5
```

More seriously, you can redefine an identifier with the same or a different type, but only in a different scope, as explained in *sidcoder*'s answer.

Here is an explanation for the preprocessor trick:

- `#define k glue(k_, __LINE__)` defines the preprocessor symbol `k` to
  as a new symbol formed by concatenating `k_` and the value of `__LINE__`, a preprocessor built-in symbol expanded to the source line number during preprocessing.
- The `glue` macro must be defined as above because of arcane intricacies of the preprocessing specification well beyond the scope of the question.
- the effect of this definition is every occurrence of `k` after the definition is replaced with `k_xxx` where `xxx` is the line number of the occurrence.

The `main()` function looks like this after preprocessing:

```
int main() {
    int k_8 = 5;      printf("k = %d\n", k_8);
    float k_9 = 12.5; printf("k = %g\n", k_9);
    return 0;
}
```

The definitions actually define variables with different names, as long as they appear on different lines. To use these variables, you cannot write `k` beyond the line where they are defined, so this trick is of limited use indeed.

Comment: I was looking for such tricky ways (it works anyway). Sorry, but could you explain a little about the preprocessor you used. I could not find enough information on the internet.

Comment: @Ganchimeg: I amended the answer with more explanations. The C preprocessor is full of quirks and pitfalls, just like the `scanf()` specification. Mastering all of these is not required, but knowing about them will ensure you use them with caution.

Answer (score 4):

No, you cannot redefine a variable with different types within the same scope.

Although, there is one possible alternative. The same variable name can be used in a new scope or a subroutine. See the example below:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

// Subroutine
void testing()
{
   int k = 9;
   printf("k = %i\n", k);
}

// Main Routine
int main() {
    int k = 5;
        
    // New scope
    {
       printf("k = %i\n", k);
       float k = 12.5;
       printf("k = %5.2f\n", k);
       testing();
    }
   
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
k = 5
k = 12.50
k = 9
```

Comment: This works because `k` is in a different scope in each of these cases. That’s not what the OP is asking about.

Comment: well, look, question is about "Is there any possible way to do like this?" - while he knows that this is not working right away. So I showed this option. The question also does NOT tell that it has to be in the same scope. Sometimes this can be useful, ... use all the same variables again, but in a local scope only ... or just to make sure that loop variable "i" is really local (but this can lead to bad style).

Comment: *Is there any possible way to do like this?*... There is, but for obfuscation only :)

Comment: @pion For all we know this is *exactly* what the OP is asking about!  (Seriously.)